# Rhino.Mocks with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rhino-mocks

I just installed rhinomocks via nuget package manager in vs2010.

I tried to import rhino.mocks

```
Imports Rhino.Mocks
```

but it keeps saying

`"Namespace or type specificed in the Imports 'Rhino.Mocks' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found.  Make sure the namespace or the type is defined contains at least one public member.  Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases."`

Does anyone know what's wrong?

I checked the references under My Project and I do see Rhino.Mocks as part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I just downloaded rhinomock 3.6 from the site and added references manually and worked.  Not sure why it didn't work when I added it via nuget.  But problem solved!